# graph implementation using adjacency list and HashSets

Tags: graph, binary-search-tree, hashset

when I started to implement graph as adjacency list , I noticed that 
the running time of checking if v1 ajdacent to v2 is O(V)

```
bool isAdjacent(int v1, int v2){    
    for(int i = 0; i < V; ++i){    
        if(this.graph[v1][i] == v2){ return true; }    
    }   
    return false;    
}
```

the loop works till V (number of vertices) so it's O(V)

can I use HashSet instead of ArrayList or vector ?

it was `ArrayList< ArrayList<Integer> > graph;`

or `Vector< Vector<Integer> > graph;`

now I want to know why can't we create

ArrayList< HashSet > graph;

this will make bool isAdjacent(int v1, int v2); O(1) because searching in HashSet is order O(1) ?

if hashset can't be used because it takes extra memory than needen , what about binary Trees? ?

ArrayList< Binary_Tree > graph;

in this case searching will be O( lg V) better then O(V)

can any one help , why this implementation wasn't created before ??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can (and should) use a HashMap, for each vertex, to store its neighbors-list.

For example, for V1 create the following HashMap:

```
HashMap<Integer, Boolean> v1Adjacents = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
```

During `init` you go  over the adjacent list of every vertex and update it, then it'll be easy to check if V2 is adjacent:

```
if(v1Adjacents.get(V2) != null){
...
}
```